# Can this be viewed as a random walk?

Tags: probability, stopping-times

Suppose I start flipping independent fair coins $c_1,c_2,\dots$. I want to look at "windows" of length $n$, e.g., $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ would be the first window, $(c_2,\dots,c_{n+1})$ would be the second window, etc. Let $X_i$ be the number of Heads I see in the window $(c_{1+i},\dots,c_{n+i})$. Thus $X_0 \sim \text{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{2})$.

Ultimately I would like to find the expected time for $X_i$ to exceed a particular value. I would like to do this by viewing $(X_i)$ as a random walk. (Or is there a better way to compute this?)

My first thought was that each time we "shift the window" we discard a coin and add a coin. With probability $1/2$ the coin we add shows the same thing as the coin discarded, i.e., $P(X_{i+1}=X_i)=1/2$. With probability $1/2$ they show different things. Half of that time we discard a Head and add a Tail, so $P(X_{i+1}=X_i-1)=1/4$, and half of that time we discard a Tail and add a Head, so $P(X_{i+1}=X_i+1)=1/4$. However, this is not totally correct. If $(X_i)$ did follow the transition probabilities above, then it would be possible for $(X_i)$ to go negative, yet we know the number of heads in each window is always nonnegative. (Also, that walk could exceed $n$, but the number of heads in each window is always less than or equal to $n$).

My next thought is perhaps $(X_i)$ is the random walk described above, but conditioned to remain in $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$. How would I prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 1):

The random walk view can lead to outcomes that are not possible in the coin flip view. For example, with $n=2$, the walk might give $X_1 = 0$, $X_2=1$, $X_3=1$, $X_4=1$, $X_5=2$.

With the coin flipping method, the first window must be $(0, 0, 0)$, then the second third and fourth are $(0, 0, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, and $(1, 0, 0)$. There is now window consistent with both these and $X_5 = 2$.

Basically the process isn't Markovian over the state space you've given.

Comment: Right, I agree it is not Markovian. Does this imply that it cannot even be a random walk with some conditioning, because that would still be Markov? Any suggestions for other ways to compute the hitting time?

Comment: The easiest way to repair it is to change the state space so that your state space is *vectors* of the past $n$ coin flips instead of just the count of the heads in the last $n$ tries.

Comment: @kccu you asked about simply conditioning it to remain in $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and my example shows that is not enough.

Comment: As for other ideas, none occurred to me immediately.

Comment: @DavisYoshida Yes, I meant some other conditioning.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I agree that is Markov, but unfortunately it is quite complicated to calculate the hitting time of the set of vectors with $\geq k$ Heads when $n$ is large (and I'd like a general formula in terms of $n$ and $k$).

Comment: @kccu Intuitively, it seems to me that it's hopeless to take another approach; you genuinely need to know the full history of the last $n$ coin throws in order to evaluate whether the condition has been met. But, perhaps a clever method exists that I simply can't see right now (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: @kccu: Hmmm -- I suppose what I just said isn't quite true. if you know $X_n$, and you know the coin throw that will "fall out" of the window in the next throw, then you can determine the transition probability for $X_{n+1}$. So maybe there's a way to leverage that somehow... not sure, though.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I agree, it seems difficult to escape knowing the whole history of the last $n$ coins. I was hoping to find some clever trick.